# Enlarging table to the whole page width

Tags: tables, table-of-contents

I have the following table:

I would like to modify this table so that:

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lrrrrrrr}
& \multicolumn{4}{c}{very long caption for the categories} \\\cline{2-5}
{category} & sample A & sample B &sample C \\
\hline
I & 7 &-9 &5 \\
II  & -2 &2 &5 \\
III & -3 &2 &2 \\
IV & -1& 4 &3 \\\\
\end{tabular}%
\end{table}
```

1. the table is as wide as the page, i.e. the column of category is leftmost and the column sample C is rightmost
2. the table content is not getting bigger
3. the columns of sample A, sample B and sample C have the same distance from each other

I would be grateful for any help!

Comment: Probably the simplest is to  use `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X rrrrrrr }... \end{tabularx}`.

Comment: You are only using 4 of the 8 specified columns.  The width of each column should be `\dimexpr 0.25\textwidth-2\tabcolsep` which you can specify using makecell or `\makebox[\dimexpr 0.25\textwidth-2\tabcolsep]...`